# Yajuj and majuj

Tags: quran

Ever since I heard about yajuj and majuj I’ve been thinking of it’s meaning. It’s really hard for me to wrap my head around the fact that colony so immensely large in numbers is locked somewhere on earth . Especially now we have satellite images and almost every inch of the earth and race of humanity is reached.

Is it possible that yajuj and majuj are descendants of people and perhaps they are not locked but once there was a partition on earth to keep these people away. Now they are free and we know of these people .

Also it says in Quran they will come upon a large water and consume it all. This doesn’t seem logical because even in large quantities you can’t possibly drain seas.

My theory is that perhaps there will be biological warfare and somehow humans will be altered in such a way that they consume large amount of waters with ease , they are extremely violent and kill everyone on their way.

Also it says that you will not win by fighting these people and only way to escape is to take refuge in mountains and hide. So perhaps these people cannot climb or tolerate high altitude.

Also I was always amazed by human fascination on very interesting genre and that is zombies. Perhaps humans take this inspiration by creating these violent human beings because Quran already mentions by yajuj and majuj of such a violence by humans that it will destroy everything on earth .

Also it says that they will experience one men’s death by a plague that Allah sends in their throat.

So if nothing could kill these human beings except a plague that also might indicate that they are not regular human beings but maybe chemically , genetically or somehow altered human beings.

I’m not trying to spread false ideas but this is something that I thought about . I would like to know other opinions about this thought. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that yajuj and majuj don’t really have a specific description. Some sources say they are a tribe of outdated people similar to cavemen whilst another source I was told were that they are short similar to fictional beings (I presume a goblin maybe). I think it’s best to read the hadeeths as it is mentioned there as well as listen to what some imams and scholars have to say. It’s a fascinating topic though, gives me goosebumps everytime I think of it.